# SQL syntax error/character recogition

Tags: mysql, function, syntax, syntax-error

when I post something into my html form, for example in the first name field, I enter in:

```
'John', i am getting the following error:
```

Error in query: .

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Smith',Address_Line_1='rtuy657tr',Address_Line_2='',City='leicester',Postcode='L' at line 1
```

I know it has something to do with the `mysql_real_escape_string ()` function, but how would I use it for inserting into a the DB. I have started the function:

```
function db_insert_preparation(){



}


$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("project1", $con);
```

This is where it needs to be used:

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO `".$table_name."` (`Group`, `Date_Of_Birth`, `Gender`, `Title`, `First_Name`, `Last_Name`, `Address_Line_1`, `Address_Line_2`, `City`, `Postcode`, `Contact_No`, `Email`, `Additional_Comment`, `Upload_File`) VALUES ('".db_insert_preparation($group)."','".$_POST[dateofbirth]."','".$_POST[gender]."','".$_POST[title]."','".$_POST[firstname]."','".$_POST[lastname]."','".$_POST[address1]."','".$_POST[address2]."','".$_POST[city]."','".$_POST[postcode]."','".$_POST[contactno]."','".$_POST[email]."','".$_POST[note]."','".$filename."' )";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL insert statement is vulnerable to SQL injection. If one of the POST values contains a double quote `"` or a newline, the statement gets corrupted and syntax errors ensue. Make sure you escape everything user-provided with [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Answer (score 0):

use mysql_real_escape_string function on `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[firstname'])`. Infact do it on all your post variables before you pass it to the SQL.

Comment: do i not need to make a customised function?

Comment: yes, before passing it to server, always filter your inputs. Otherwise it is prone SQL injections...!

Comment: is this valid? '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[firstname])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[lastname])."'